# Is there a logical error in the proof of $\sum \vdash \theta \equiv \sum \vdash \forall x\theta$?

Tags: logic

Here in "Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic", this theorem is mentioned in page $72$:

[image]

I wonder, Is this lemma true? I find some problems in the proof:

First of all, The author used (QR) which says that:
If $x$ is bounded in $\alpha$ then the following is a rule of inference. 
$<\{\alpha \rightarrow \beta\} ,\alpha \rightarrow \forall x\beta >$

The problem is that $x$ is not bounded in $[(\forall y(y=y) \vee ¬(\forall (y=y))]$ so we can't use in in this situation. Could any one please clarify that?

Comment: @Winther, I've edited the core of the question to make it precise, in fact, I should have mentioned that I find the proof problimatic. check the question again, please.

Comment: The author says "not free"; this does not necessarily means : "bounded" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the "problematic" case is :

> if $\Sigma \vdash \theta$, then $\Sigma \vdash \forall x \theta$.

You have to see the comment on page 73 and review the **Definition 2.4.6.**, page 61, with the proviso of **(QR)** rule :

> > $$\langle \{\psi \rightarrow \varphi \} , \psi \rightarrow (\forall x\varphi) \rangle$$
>
> The "not making any particular assumptions about $x$" comment is made formal by the requirement that $x$ not be free in $\varphi$.

This is often called **Generalization Theorem** and correspond to the *Natural Deduction* rule :

> > $$\frac{\Gamma \vdash A[y/x]}{\Gamma \vdash \forall x A } \quad (\forall I)$$

which means :

> The formula $∀xA$ is provable from assumptions $\Gamma$ if $A[y/x]$ is provable for an *arbitrary* $y$.

You can see Jan von Plato, [Elements of Logical Reasoning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107036593) (2013), page 122 :

> We have in the premiss a derivation of the formula $A[y/x]$, and the conclusion is $∀xA$.
>
> The following condition states in what sense $y$ is arbitrary:
>
> > The variable $y$ must not occur free in any of the assumptions $\Gamma$ the premiss  $A[y/x]$ of the rule depends on.
>
> The idea is that nothing is assumed about $y$ except that it is an object in a domain $\mathcal D$. Thus, any object in $\mathcal D$ can take its place in the derivation
>   of $A[y/x]$ from $\Gamma$, say the object $a$. If every free occurrence of $y$ in the
>   derivation is replaced by $a$, a derivation of $A[a/x]$ from $\Gamma$is obtained.

---

---

*Added*

There is a "tricky" point worth to be commented here.

Leary's statement of **Lemma 2.7.2** does not put restriction on the free variables in $\Sigma$.

As noted by the OP, in Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122384520) (2nd ed - 2001), page 117, we have :

> **GENERALIZATION THEOREM** : If $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ and $x$ does not occur free in any
>   formula in $\Gamma$, then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \varphi$.

How to justify this difference ?

We can mimick the proof of the Lemma, according to Leary's deductive calculus :

1) $x < 2$ --- assumed

2) $x < 2 \rightarrow (0=0 \rightarrow x < 2)$ -- (PC) : it is an instance of the *tautology* : $P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow P)$

3) $0=0 \rightarrow x < 2$ --- from 1) and 2) by *modus ponens*

4) $0=0 \rightarrow \forall x(x < 2)$ --- from 3) by (QR)

5) $0=0$ --- equality axiom

6) $\forall x(x < 2)$ --- from 4) and 5) by *modus ponens*.

Thus, we conclude with :

> $x < 2 \vdash \forall x(x < 2)$.

This is consistent with an application of **Lemma 2.7.2.**

With $\Sigma = \{ x < 2 \}$, we have trivially [see **Definition 2.2.1.** of *deduction*, page 50] : $\Sigma \vdash x < 2$; thus the Lemma licences us to conclude with : $\Sigma \vdash \forall x(x < 2)$.

In Enderton's system the above derivation is not correct; having $\Gamma = \{ x < 2 \}$, we cannot apply **Gen Th** because $x$ is not free in $\Gamma$; thus : $x < 2 \nvdash \forall x(x < 2)$.

We can reconcile the two calulus if we take into account [see Leary, page 74] :

> **Theorem 2.7.4 (The Deduction Theorem)** : Suppose that $\theta$ is a *sentence* and $\Sigma$ is a set of formulas. Then $\Sigma \cup \theta \vdash \phi$ if and only if 
>   $\Sigma \vdash (\theta \rightarrow \phi)$.

Due to the restriction on $\theta$, we cannot apply this theorem to the above deduction, with $\Sigma = \emptyset$ and $\theta := x < 2$, because $x$ is free in $\theta$ ($\theta$ is **not** a *sentence*) and thus we have :

> $\nvdash (x < 2) \rightarrow \forall x (x < 2)$

as expected, because the formula $P(x) \rightarrow \forall xP(x)$ is clearly **not** valid, as we can see from the instance above, that is false in the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers.

In Enderton's system we have [see page 118] :

> **DEDUCTION THEOREM** : If $\Gamma, \gamma \vdash \varphi$, then $\Gamma \vdash (\gamma → \varphi)$.

In this case, there is no limitation to $\gamma$ being a *sentence*; due to the fact that **Generalization Th** in Enderton's system does not licences the derivation of $\forall xP(x)$ from $P(x)$, this is enough to prevent from the derivation of the invalid : $P(x) \rightarrow \forall xP(x)$.

Comment: The problem is that the author used a rule of inference ${A\rightarrow B}, A\rightarrow \forall xA$ where $x$ is NOT free in $A$. In the given deduction in the proof, $x$ is bounded in $[(\forall y(y=y)\vee ¬(\forall y(y=y))]$, So he can't use (QR) in this deduction. This is my objection. Could you clarify where I went wrong, please?

Comment: @MathsLover - in the proof the author apply (QR) to $[(∀y(y=y)∨¬(∀y(y=y))] \rightarrow \theta$; thus the "$\psi$" of the rule is $[(∀y(y=y)∨¬(∀y(y=y))]$ and in it $x$ (the variable to be quantified) is **not** free (it is not free simply because it is not present).

Comment: Oh, thank you for clarifying that. I have a  question, How is "not making any particular assumptions" is made formal by requiring it Not being free? It seems that not making any particular assumptions means that we can interpret the varaible to be any element in the universe of the strucutre. This is satisfied if the term is free. Could you clarify that, please?

Comment: @MathsLover - If I "say" :$x > 0$, I'm making an "assumptipon" regarding the "possible values" of $x$. In this case, an application of the rule gives us : $x > 0 \rightarrow \forall x(x > 0)$, which is not true in the structure $\mathbb N$ of *natural numbers* (because we can assign to the free var $x$ the value $1$, making the conditional $TRUE \rightarrow FALSE$, which is $FALSE$). Thus, in general, it is not *valid* : $P(x) \rightarrow \forall xP(x)$; this is the reason for the restriction : we want that the rule is *sound*, i.e. that it does not deduce invalid formulae.

Comment: Ok, great. But I looked at Enderton's and found that he adds the condition that $x$ is not free in every $a\in \sum$ which agrees with what you are saying. Wasn't it necessary that the author adds this condition too? Or is it mentioned implicitly?

Comment: @MathsLover - see *Addendum* to the answer above... :)